# Laravel Update Database with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.7

Hey guys I'm using laravel 5.7 and I'm attempting to make a ajax post request to update my database. The ajax would post based on a checkbox on change function. Example if i toggle off the checkbox it would send a request and update my status to `Inactive` in my `User` table. After attempting it, i had an error of `405 (Method Not Allowed)`. Anyone able to note what am i doing wrong? Sorry if there are some wrong codes or syntax in my codes as I'm very new to Ajax. Any help would be appreciated.

**Ajax**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:'get',
        url:'{!!URL::to('findStatus')!!}',
        success:function(data){
            for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){

                var checkBox = document.getElementById('switch-'+data[i].u_id);

                console.log(checkBox);

                if(data[i].status == "Active"){
                    $('#switch-'+data[i].u_id).prop('checked',true);
                }

                else if(data[i].status == "Inactive")
                {
                    $('#switch-'+data[i].u_id).prop('checked',false);
                } 


                $('#switch-'+data[i].u_id).change(function(){
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url : '{!!URL::to('admin/{admin}')!!}',
                        success:function(data){
                            console.log(data);
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        },
        error:function(data){
            console.log('ERROR');
        }
    });
});
```

**Route**

```
Route::resource('admin','AdminController');  << I'm using the update method from the resource controller
```

**Controller**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);
    if($user->status == "Active"){
        $user->status = "Inactive";
        $user->save();
    }else{
        $user->status = "Active";
        $user->save();
    }
    return response()->json($user);
}
```

**Form**

```
{!!Form::open(array('action'=>['AdminController@update',$item->u_id],'method'=>'POST','id'=>'update'))!!}
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="u_id" id="u_id" value="{{$item->u_id}}">
    <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="switch-{{$item->u_id}}" class="custom-control-input">
        <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
    </label>
    {{-- <button class="btn btn-primary">Update</button> --}}
{{Form::hidden('_method','PUT')}}
{!!Form::close()!!}
```

**UPDATE**

I have managed to "pass" the u_id to my post request by getting the id through `target.id` and splitting it with `-`. It is not the most elegant way but it works. But now im getting an error

> POST http://manageme.test/admin/%7B2%7D 500 (Internal Server Error)

Here is what i have updated in my codes.

```
$('#switch-'+data[i].u_id).change(function(e){

    console.log(e.target.id);

    var s = e.target.id;
    var split = s.split('-')[1];

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: `{!!url('admin/')!!}/{${split}}`,
        data: { _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}", _method: "PUT" },
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    }); 
});
```

these are inside my update controller

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);
    if($user->status == "Active"){
        $user->status = "Inactive";
        $user->save();
    }else{
        $user->status = "Active";
        $user->save();
    }
    return response()->json($user);
}
```

I have also looked at the error inside the network tab of the dev tools the error message from laravel is `message: "Trying to get property 'status' of non-object"`. I think it cant find any `$user` inside the update method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

I managed to fix it the problem was coming from the route trying to pass the `u_id` of the user and finding the user's data. So instead of typing the url inside, i made a variable to pass the route and u_id together. Here are the codes

**Ajax**

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});


$.ajax({
    type:'get',
    url:'{!!url('findStatus')!!}',
    success:function(data){
        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){

            var checkBox = document.getElementById('switch-'+data[i].u_id);


            if(data[i].status == "Active"){
                $('#switch-'+data[i].u_id).prop('checked',true);
            }

            else if(data[i].status == "Inactive")
            {
                $('#switch-'+data[i].u_id).prop('checked',false);
            } 


            $('#switch-'+data[i].u_id).change(function(e){
                var s = e.target.id;
                var split = s.split('-')[1];
                var url = '{{route('admin.update','split')}}';

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: url,
                    data: { _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}", _method: "PUT" ,u_id: split},
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log(data['message']);
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    },
    error:function(data){
        console.log('ERROR');
    }
});
```

**Update method**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $user = User::find($request['u_id']);

    if($user->status == "Active")
    {
        $user->status = "Inactive";
        $user->save();
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Update to Inactive']);
    }else{
        $user->status = "Active";
        $user->save();
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Update to Active']);
    }       
}
```

**DONT** forget to add the meta tag onto the document header for csrf token

```
 <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of: 
"{!!URL::to('admin/{admin}')!!}" 
write :
`{!!url('admin/')!!}/${data[i].u_id}`
and add _token and _method params to your ajax data
and write like this:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: '{!!url('findStatus')!!}',
    success: function (data) {
      data.forEach(d => {
        console.log(d);
        if (d.status == "Active") {
          $(`#switch-${d.u_id}`).prop('checked', true);
        }
        else if (d.status == "Inactive") {
          $(`#switch-${d.u_id}`).prop('checked', false);
        }
        $(`#switch-${d.u_id}`).change(function () {
          console.log(d);
          //changed###########
          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: `{!!url('admin/')!!}/${d.u_id}`,
            data: { _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}", _method: "PUT" },
            success: function (data) {
              console.log(data);
            }
          });
          //###################
        });
      });
    },
    error: function (data) {
      console.log('ERROR');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Now im getting a different error `Cannot read property 'u_id' of undefined`. I noticed that error will occur whenever i try to use the my `data` inside the `.change` function. I have also tried to debug by adding a `console.log(data[i].u_id)` inside the on change function but before the ajax. It doesn't return anything in the console. Any ideas?

Comment: After some research i found out its because i can't pass a variable from my `success:function(data)` to another function which is why it cant read the property..but still figuring out how to solve the problem

Comment: I tried and there was no problem for url findStatus I added a function that return [['u_id' => 1],['u_id' => 2],['u_id' => 3], ['u_id' => 4],['u_id' => 5],['u_id' => 6]]; and all things worked fine. try again with my edited code and see console logs

Comment: check your data returned from findStatus url that data is correct? has u_id?

Comment: Didnt work.. the error still pointing that the `u_id` is undefined at the url line

Comment: what's result of findStatus url? what's returned?

Comment: `created_at: "2018-10-20 15:38:23"
email: "james@james.com"
name: "James"
picture: "user.jpg"
status: "Active"
u_id: 2
updated_at: "2018-10-20 15:38:23"`

Comment: i did a `console.log(data[i]);` inside the success:function forloop and that was the result

Comment: Is data array? or data is one user object? I think data is one object

Comment: this is inside the findStatus controller 

`public function findStatus()
    {
        $data = User::all();

        return response()->json($data);
    }`

Comment: i have updated my codes please do help me check thank you